# How to remove and add css styles using javascript - added style not reflected in UI

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have created a stackblitz for my code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxdatatable-sort-test-qfeux3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Basically i am trying to add a custom icon if sorting is not performed on the columns.
If any sorting is performed, I am retaining the existing icon.

While trying to add the custom icon, I am removing the existing classnames and adding the new icon.
When i debug, i can see the new custom icon getting added, but after execution , the added custom icon is getting removed.

Comment: I noticed that the new custom icon is getting added from my code and then gets removed from code which is part of library ng_zone.ts. Is there any way to prevent this overriding if code from library and execute only my code?

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That tiny e/f at the end of the column is the icon you mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and after the following changes, I am able to see the icon change. Try to check if this is the problem.

```
onSort(event){
    const name: string = event.column.name;
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    console.log(event);
    if(name=="company") {
      event.sorts.push({"id":0});
    }
     if(name =="name") {
      event.sorts.push({"id":1});
    }

     if(name=="age") {
      event.sorts.push({"id":3});
    }
     for (let i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) { 
       console.log("id value",event.sorts[1].id);
        console.log("i value",i);
       if(event.sorts[1].id == i){
         console.log("inside id value",event.sorts[1].id);
         console.log("inside i value",i);
         console.log("do nothing");
       } else {
         console.log('change icon');
         // here i am removing the existing icon and adding the custom icon
             document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[i].classList.remove(
           "datatable-icon-down");
           document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[i].classList.remove("sort-desc");
            document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[i].classList.remove(
           "datatable-icon-up");
           document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[i].classList.remove("sort-asc");
  // running in debug mode, during execution i can see custom icon getting added, but after execution i am not able to see the added icon, 
    if (i == 2) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[i].classList.remove("datatable-iconCustom");
       } else {
           setTimeout(()=>{

           document.getElementsByClassName("sort-btn")[i].classList.add("datatable-iconCustom");             
         },10);  

       }
       }
        }  
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Luciano. Works perfect!! . I have a query here. Is there any way to avoid  this comparison. name=="company" and compare the with some other attribute, as the comparison with name wil break if the company text changes.

Comment: I could suggest saving the value to be verified (id provided by db or similar) in the html and then using it in the sort function. Maybe directly in a parameter of the sort function. For example something like (sort) = "onSort($event, id)". Obviously it depends on how the data is structured for uploading

Comment: It's not an Angular way. the angular way is use ngClass, see https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass